# Error running a Windows Scheduled Task under System Account

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, .net-4.5

I want to create a scheduled task to run under the "LOCAL SERVICE" account. The task will call a C# program (.NET 4.5). To do a POC, i kept the C# program to be simple - one that just writes a text to  a Console.

The taskscheduler task is set to run when not logged on. I have made sure that the c# executable has permissions for the LOCAL SERVICE (Read, REad and Execute).

When I run the scheduled task, i get the below error in the event log:

`Task Scheduler failed to start instance "{e719a65e-d4fb-4515-9fc9-3635fe69e378}" of "\Testing LOCAL SERVICE"  task for user "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE" . Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942405.`

However, if I run the same task under LOCAL SERVICe by pointing to known programs like mspaint or notepad, the task runs without errors. I am not sure what is so specific with permissions for the C# program.

Appreciate some thoughts on this.

Comment: Unable to reproduce what you describe. You do not need to set any permissions on the exe but it must be on a local disk.

Comment: For reference, 2147942405 =  0x80070005 = COR_E_UNAUTHORIZEDACCESS
You should verify that the program - `.exe` file and containing folder - has permissions. Also verify that it's really local - mapped network drives only apply to the user session that created them.

Comment: The .exe is on a local drive (c:\TestFolder). The .exe and the containing folder have Read/Execute permissions for the LOCAL SERVICE user. Thanks for confirming my research that it is related to some access issue....but looks like I have the required permissions.

Answer (score 3):

The user used to run the task must have right permission on the folder that host the .exe file.
Right click on the folder > Properties > Security > Edit > Add > And try to add "full control"  permission.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From here: [Task Scheduler failed to start. Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726. What does this mean?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/task-scheduler-failed-to-start-additional-data/96994b77-d690-4403-8b51-4e1d0ae998e1)

The change of password has a role causing that error.

The quickest fix:

In Task Scheduler, open the scheduled job properties, go to settings.

[image: screenshot]

The last listed option should read, "If the task is already running, the following rule applies:"

Select "Stop the existing instance", click OK and exit.

This should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I having the same error code "2147942405" when I change the User. At the end, I managed resolved it by enable the "Run with highest privileges"

[image]